# how to retrive nested document and arrays values in elasticsearch

Tags: java, json, scala, elasticsearch

I have a following document

```
{
  "_index" : "Testdb",
  "_type" : "artWork",
  "_id" : "0",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source":{"uuid":0,"ArtShare":{"TotalArtShares":0,"pricePerShare":0,"ArtworkUuid":12,"AvailableShares":0,"SoldShares":0},"StatusHistoryList":[{"ArtWorkDate":"2015-08-26T13:20:17.725+05:00","ArtworkStatus":"ACTIVE"}]}
}
```

i want to access/retrieve the value of `ArtShare` and its attributes and values of array `StatusHistoryList`

i am doing like this

```
val get=client.prepareGet("Testdb","artWork",Id.toString())
        .setOperationThreaded(false)
        .setFields("uuid","ArtShare","StatusHistoryList"
            )
        .execute()
        .actionGet()
        if(get.isExists())
        {
        uuid=get.getField("uuid").getValue.toString().toInt
       //how to fetch `artShare` whole nested document and array elements `StatusHistoryListof`  
     }
```

**UPDATE**
if i do this

```
 val get=client.prepareGet("Testdb","artWork",Id.toString())
            .setOperationThreaded(false)
            .setFields("uuid","ArtShare","StatusHistoryList"
                ,"_source","ArtShare.TotalArtShares")
            .execute()
            .actionGet()
            if(get.isExists())
            {
            uuid=get.getField("uuid").getValue.toString().toInt
           var totalShares= get.getField("ArtShare.TotalArtShares").getValue.toString().toInt 
         }
```

then following exception thrown

```
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: field [ArtShare] isn't a leaf field
    at org.elasticsearch.index.get.ShardGetService.innerGetLoadFromStoredFields(ShardGetService.java:368)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.get.ShardGetService.innerGet(ShardGetService.java:210)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.get.ShardGetService.get(ShardGetService.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.get.TransportGetAction.shardOperation(TransportGetAction.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.get.TransportGetAction.shardOperation(TransportGetAction.java:44)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportShardSingleOperationAction$ShardTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportShardSingleOperationAction.java:297)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportShardSingleOperationAction$ShardTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportShardSingleOperationAction.java:280)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler$RequestHandler.doRun(MessageChannelHandler.java:279)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:36)
```

please guide me how to fetch these values

Comment: For ArtShare  it should work like this :
"ArtShare.TotalArtShares","ArtShare.pricePerShare","ArtShare.ArtworkUuid"

Comment: no its not working it throws exception please see my edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah Actually the problem is that you have mentioned both "ArtShare" and "ArtShare.TotalArtShares" in the fields array. So it throws exception as  you have already retrieved complete ArtShare object.

So please mention the fields that you want, If you want specified nested values then no need to access complete parent object.

Try this:

```
val get=client.prepareGet("Testdb","artWork",Id.toString())
        .setOperationThreaded(false)
        .setFields("uuid","StatusHistoryList",
            "ArtShare.TotalArtShares")
        .execute()
        .actionGet()
        if(get.isExists())
        {
        uuid=get.getField("uuid").getValue.toString().toInt
       var totalShares= get.getField("ArtShare.TotalArtShares" 
     }
```

And if you want complete "ArtShare" object then simply write :

```
val get=client.prepareGet("Testdb","artWork",Id.toString())
    .setOperationThreaded(false)
    .setFields("uuid","ArtShare","StatusHistoryList"
        )
    .execute()
    .actionGet()
    if(get.isExists())
    {
    uuid=get.getField("uuid").getValue.toString().toInt
   //how to fetch `artShare` whole nested document and array elements `StatusHistoryListof`  
 }
```

Comment: when i do this  log.info("getting artshare TotalArtShares values ",get.getField("ArtShare.TotalArtShares")) it returns null with setField("uuid","StatusHistoryList",
            "ArtShare.TotalArtShares") but values exits when i do curl get its not null there ...why is this happening ?

Comment: May be you should try getField("ArtShare"). This will help you get the json of ArtShare and you can retrieve the "TotalArtShares" from that.

Comment: no its working with ArtShare.TotalShares now thank you do you have any idea how can i retrieve the StatusHistoryList  array ?

Comment: Please specify what is problem you getting with StatusHistoryList because if you add this to fields it must be in the result.

Comment: i have posted this issue here please look at it and help me please i wil be very thankful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269751/how-to-get-nested-types-in-elasticsearch